# Sending the document in email + gridview

Tags: c#

I have a gridview which looks like

```
                   ID       Filename      Type
-----------------------------------------------------
Share  view        1      Tiger           .doc
share  view        2      Lion            .xls
share  view        3      dog             .ppt
```

When I click on view, the document will be opened and we can edit it. I want the share link to perform some specific function. If I click on share, it should ask to enter the email, and send the respective document to the email written. Ex. If i click on share where the document is tiger, that document should be sent to the email written.

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried?

Comment: My question is when i click on share of first row, it should ask me to write the email, and once i write it, Tiger document should be emailed to the address written. How can i do this?

Comment: Ok but what is your question exactly? How can i differ which Row was selected? Or how can i send an Email? What is the Specific question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution.Here is a piece of code used.

In gridview, for share hyperlink i used:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"FileName","Share.aspx?FileName={0}" ) %>'
                                    Text="Share"></asp:HyperLink>
                       </ItemTemplate>
                      </asp:TemplateField>
```

In share.aspx page

```
string datalink;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.TextBox2.Text = Request.QueryString[0];
        datalink = this.TextBox2.Text;
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create the mail message
            string strFrom = "abcd@gmail.com";
            string strTo = TextBox1.Text;
            string strCC = TextBox3.Text;
            string strSubject = "Document shared";
            string strMsg = " The document has been shared with you. Please check the attachment.";
            string myPath = @"C:\Visual Studio 2008\Data\";
            MailMessage objMailMsg = new MailMessage(strFrom, strTo);

            objMailMsg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            objMailMsg.Subject = strSubject;
            objMailMsg.Body = strMsg;
            objMailMsg.CC.Add(strCC);
            Attachment at = new Attachment(myPath + datalink);
            objMailMsg.Attachments.Add(at);
            objMailMsg.Priority = MailPriority.High;
            objMailMsg.IsBodyHtml = true;

            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            smtp.Send(objMailMsg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```